# Conveying 'first few' as in 'the first few terms'

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

I don't know how to convey 'the first few' as in the following sentences:

> 1. Write the first few terms of the following series.
> 2. We will quickly go through the first few slides.
> 3. The first fews days wil be difficult.
> 4. The first few sentences of your abstract should state the subject of the study.

Google Translate, Deepl, Linguee and Reverso ignore *few* and convey only *first* by *premiers/premières* but I am wondering if native speakers have an idiomatic way to convey *few* as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

“*Les premiers …*” is an adequate translation of “the first few …”. We (meaning French speakers from France) wouldn't use “*les premiers …*” if it can mean a large number of items. The word-by-word translation “<sup>?</sup>*les quelques premiers*” is possible if you want to insist that you mean a small number of items, but it's uncommon (contrast frequencies: [the first few / few](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+first+few%2Ffew&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) ≈ 1% in English, but [les quelques premi(ers|ères) / quelques](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=les+quelques+premiers+%2B+les+quelques+premi%C3%A8res%2Fquelques&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3) ≈ 0.003% in French).

To reinforce the “first few” aspect, we might use other words within the semantic field of beginnings, for example:

- “*Commencez à écrire les premiers termes de la série.*”
- “*Nous allons passer rapidement sur le début de la présentation.*”
- “*Les tous premiers jours seront difficiles.*” (Note that this stronger than “the first few”, more like “the very first few”.) (Note that conservative writers write “*les tout premiers*”, which is somewhat logical because *tout* is an adverb and thus should be invariable — but the feminine form would be “*les toutes premières heures*”.)
- “*Le résumé doit commencer par quelques phrases résumant le champ d'étude.*”

Comment: What a thorough answer! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the word *quelques*:

- “Écrivez les quelques premiers termes …”
- “On va rapidement parcourir les quelques premières …”

*et cetera.*

Comment: *les quelques premiers* ou *les quelques premières* ne me semble pas très idiomatique.

Comment: Je trouve plus idiomatiques les tours que Gilles a expliqués mais ce n'est pas inusité pour moi et j'ai trouvé que le président de la République a [employé](https://www.vie-publique.fr/discours/204296-declaration-de-m-emmanuel-macron-president-de-la-republique-sur-les-r) ça spontanément à l'oral.